# System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox in .NetVersion 4.0/4.5 behaves differently in windows7 and windows8 OS's

Tags: .net, wpf, windows-8, compatibility

Technically,
We are using System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox in our application. This behaves differently in Windows7 and Windows8 OS's.

Practically,
I've recreated the issue via a simple sample application.
I've created a sample application that will rise a MessageBox when (TextBox)textBox1 PreviewLostKeyboardFocus() has occured.

I first ran the sample application in Windows7. Now, I pressed tab from the textbox1 so, PreviewLostKeyboardFocus() called;
MessageBox called; I clicked MessageBox->"OK" button; MessageBox closed; The focus retained in textbox1.

Now, the same sample solution I ran in Windows8. Now, I pressed tab from the textbox1 so, PreviewLostKeyboardFocus() called;MessageBox called; I clicked MessageBox->"OK" button; MessageBox closed; Again the
PreviewLostKeyboardFocus() has been called;I clicked MessageBox->"OK" button;
MessageBox closed; Again the PreviewLostKeyboardFocus() has been called.
So what happens is, the MessageBox does not close. It comes again and again.
I could not edit my textbox1.
So, I need to close the entire application from the Task Manager.

I've given my sample application code here for reference. This might seems simple issue. But we are using this functionality in more places in our Big Application. So any easy solution will help us to save more time of our support.
This issue created in .Net Framework 4.0 / 4.5. For .Net Framework 3.5 it works fine in both the OS's

### Sample WPF Application :

### XAML CODE:

```
<Window x:Class="wpf_forms_msg_box.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="txt1" Width="200" Height="35" Margin="40,37,277,247" TabIndex="0" 
     PreviewLostKeyboardFocus="txt1_PreviewLostKeyboardFocus_1" Text="Press Tab"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txt2" Width="200" Height="35" Margin="40,89,277,195" TabIndex="1"/>
    <Button x:Name="btn1" Content="Button1" Width="200" Height="35" Margin="40,144,277,140" TabIndex="2"/>
</Grid>
```

### CS Code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace wpf_forms_msg_box
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        txt1.Focus();
    }

    private void txt1_PreviewLostKeyboardFocus_1(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("1");
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("1");
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("2");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: So you're expecting the same results on Windows 7 and Windows 8 I guess. The code here states you're expecting three MessageBoxes, right?

Comment: Did you try not using the PreviewLostKeyboardFocus, but instead the LostKeyboardFocus-event?

Comment: Jerking the focus away in a focusing event is very troublesome.  Using LostKeyboardFocus solves your problem.

Comment: Hi Akku, yes I'm expecting only 3 messagebox and the focus returning to textbox. But the MessageBox never ends (it closes and comes again and again). So, I need to close the entire application from the Task Manager. Then that LostKeyboardFocus-event I tried, yes it works fine. But the above piece of code we use in our whole application. So it is difficult to change everywhere. If there is anyother solution it'll be really time saving.

Comment: @user2641047 Hello, I am from .NET Framework compatibility Team. We would like to understand this better. I see that you have opened Microsoft Connect bug. We are looking into it but we need your help to understand this better. I have posted on Connect but maybe you didn't get a chance to respond. Hopefully, you would be same to see this message. Could you contact us on netfx45compat at Microsoft dot com for discussion? Thanks!